# ¿Como subir imagen desde un celular al servidor PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

Tengo un problema para subir imágenes al servidor desde un dispositivo móvil (celular). Cuando ejecuto mi aplicación web desde el computador me funciona todo correctamente, las imágenes suben sin problemas. Pero cuando lo hago desde un celular no me cargan las o la imagen que se selecciona.

Este código no es directamente el que quiero solucionar, pero es prácticamente el mismo con menos validaciones, pero igual, tampoco sube la imagen cuando abro la página desde el celular (Con S.O Android).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('form[name="frmname[]"]').on("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var nombre = $("#filename").val();
  if (nombre =! "") {
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'enlace.php',
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data) {
         alert(data);
    },
    fail: function(error){
     alert(error);
    }
      });
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="http://i0.wp.com/www.hidromasa.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/icono-gota-agua-Hidromasa.png?fit=512%2C512" type="image/ico" />

    <title></title>
  </head>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <form name="frmname[]"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="form-group ">
            <label>Nombre:</label>
            <input type="text" id="filename[]" name="frmname" required="required">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group ">
            <label>Subir archivo:</label>
            <input type="file" id="file" name="file" multiple>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
 
    <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="assets/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <script src="assets/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- JS -->
  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

```
if ($_FILES["imagen"]['error']==0) {

    if ($_FILES["imagen"]['type']=="image/png" || $_FILES["imagen"]['type']=="image/jpg" || $_FILES["imagen"]['type']=="image/jpeg") {

        $target_path = "../";
        $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['imagen']['name']); 

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
            { 
                echo "El archivo ". basename( $_FILES['imagen']['name']). " ha sido subido";

            } else{
                echo "Ha ocurrido un error con el archivo ". basename( $_FILES['imagen']['name']) ;
            }   
    }else{echo $_FILES["imagen"]['type']." Solo se pueden subir archivos tipo JPG, PNG Y JPEG.";}

    }else{

        echo "Por favor seleccione un archivo para subir";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Esto podría ser por que en los celulares tienes que guardar los archivos en una ruta especifica tal que "/storage/emulated/0/nombre_de_tu_carpeta" o en una sdcard "/sdcard/download".

Comment: creo que al parecer tienes toda la razón, subir un archivo de otra carpera distinta a la de /storage/emulated/0/nombre_de_tu_carpeta **usted sabe como lo puedo solucionar**

Comment: Vale, no tiene nada que ver que lo ejecutes desde el móvil porque la web está en un servidor y es donde se tiene que guardar. Te voy a poner un ejemplo de cómo lo haría yo ya que creo que no es necesario que tengas un ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Yo haría que el formulario llamara directamente al archivo PHP ya que suele ser más seguro. Tendrás que asegurarte de que la ruta del archivo al que llamas en el action del formulario está bien (importante).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="http://i0.wp.com/www.hidromasa.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/icono-gota-agua-Hidromasa.png?fit=512%2C512" type="image/ico" />
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <form action="enlace.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="form-group ">
            <label>Nombre:</label>
            <input type="text" id="filename" name="filename" required="required">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group ">
            <label>Subir archivo:</label>
            <input type="file" id="file" name="file" multiple>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
 
    <!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Ahora vamos con el archivo php. Te voy a poner en varios puntos la comanda "echo" para ver que hasta dicho punto llegan bien los datos y un "die" para que el programa pare y se más fácil ver los errores.

```
<?php

$nombre = $_POST['filename'];
//echo $nombre; die;  //Descomenta esto para ver que el nombre el input nombre llega bien.

if ($_FILES["file"]['error']==0) {

//echo "La imagen no da errores"; die;  //Descomenta esto para ver que no da error.

   if ($_FILES["file"]['type']=="image/png" || $_FILES["file"]['type']=="image/jpg" || $_FILES["file"]['type']=="image/jpeg") {

    //echo "Formato correcto"; die;  //Descomenta esto para ver que el formato es correcto.

    $target_path = "../";
    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); 

       if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
        { 
            echo "El archivo ". basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). " ha sido subido"; //die;   //Descoemnta esto pa ver el mensaje anterior

        } else{

            echo "Ha ocurrido un error con el archivo ". basename( $_FILES['file']['name']) ; //die;   //Descoemnta esto pa ver el mensaje anterior

        }   
   }else{
     echo $_FILES["file"]['type']." Solo se pueden subir archivos tipo JPG, PNG Y JPEG.";  //die;   //Descoemnta esto pa ver el mensaje anterior
   }

}else{

    echo "Por favor seleccione un archivo para subir"; //die;   //Descoemnta esto pa ver el mensaje anterior
}
?>
```

Te recomiendo que vayas flitrando y viendo donde se te está quedando. Y de encontrar el error te intentaré dar otra solución.

Comment: Nada compadre, cuando hago las pruebas siempre se me va para el condicional **echo "Por favor seleccione un archivo para subir";** entonces creo que el problema es como un permiso de android de que me deje subir servidor la imagen proveniente del la ruta `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camara` que es donde necesito que suban las imagenes porque ayer ensaye con otra imagen proveniente de la ruta `/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images"` y de una subio. **Por favor necesito ayuda con este caso**

Comment: La verdad que yo el if ($_FILES["imagen"]['error']==0) no lo había visto nunca. Prueba a quitar ese if y a ver si luego te deja hacer algo.

Comment: **Nada brother**, eso sigue igual se me entra echo `$_FILES["imagen"]['type']." Solo se pueden subir archivos tipo JPG, PNG Y JPEG.";` es como si no agarrara la imagen que proviene de la ruta `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camara` las imágenes de la otra ruta si las sube esto esta muy raro no se que hacer

Comment: He editado el código php, quizás la culpa sea de que $_FILES["imagen"] no existe ya que en tu html el nombre del input es file. Deberías de cambiarlos por $_FILES["file"].

Comment: No brother eso no tiene nada que ver, en ultimas no puede con este problema ya después mirare como lo soluciono. De todos modo muchas gracias brother

Answer (score 0):

cambia la linea: `$target_path = "../";`

por tu ruta destino por favor.  y asi podrás subir archivos desde tu celular al servidor

```
$target_path = "imagenes/doctores/";
```

Código completo:

```
if ($_FILES["file"]['error']==0) {

    if ($_FILES["file"]['type']=="image/png" || $_FILES["file"]['type']=="image/jpg" || $_FILES["file"]['type']=="image/jpeg") {

        $target_path = "imagenes/doctores/";
        $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); 

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
            { 
                echo "El archivo ". basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). " ha sido subido";

            } else{
                echo "Ha ocurrido un error con el archivo ". basename( $_FILES['file']['name']) ;
            }   
    }else{echo $_FILES["file"]['type']." Solo se pueden subir archivos tipo JPG, PNG Y JPEG.";}

    }else{

        echo "Por favor seleccione un archivo para subir";
    }
```